# AppId or GUID of a Running Service

Tags: networking, ssl, netsh

My instructions are to

The default port used by a Performance Center host service is 8731.
To configure SSL on a host for port 8731, refer to the Microsoft Web Site: How To Configure a Port with an SSL Certificate, using the following URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx.

I am at a step where i need to run

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000
>   certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6
>   appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}

I was able to find everything except appid

if i just give any random value then i get error

> "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session
>   does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

[image: Error on nets http add sslcert]

This Link https://help.screenconnect.com/index.php?title=Installing_and_binding_an_SSL_certificate_on_Windows
says use empty GUID {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
But that also fails for me
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use any valid GUID. It is only used to identify the binding later.

Comment: can you give an example? how do i find a valid GUID?

Comment: Also as you can see based on my screenshot i tried a GUID and it didn't work

Comment: I am not sure if that is a valid GUID. Please follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313422/generate-guid-in-windows-with-batch-file) thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076915/ssl-certificate-add-failed-when-binding-to-port this solved my issue but your answer is correct as to what i asked, GUID doesn't matter which is what i asking. I was asking the wrong question

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The following method worked for me. It will generate a valid GUID & will get placed on {%NewGUID%}.

```
For /F %%a In ('Powershell -Command "$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"') DO (Set NewGUID=%%a)

Netsh.exe Http Add SSLCert IPPort="0.0.0.0:8731" Certhash="0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6" CertStoreName="My" AppID="{%NewGUID%}"
```